# Regex to find two patterns and extract values

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i am wanting to extract some values from one column to another, however i am facing some difficulties with the regex operator. I would like to take two values (61-150) and (1,1-800 GQ) and extract them to a new column that is named 'BOXES'. However, I do not know regexes that well and i can only seem to take all digit values. How can i get it so the two values (61-150) and (1,1-800 GQ) go to the boxes column and the box description to then change values to be without those digits.

```
df = pd.read_csv('boxstore.csv')
df['BOXES'] = None
# Defining indexes for desired columns
index_description = df.columns.get_loc('BOX DESCRIPTION')
index_boxing = df.columns.get_loc('BOXES')

# Creating a pattern to be extracted
boxing_pattern = r'\((\d+-\d+)\)'
# For loop to iterate through rows to find and extract pattern to 'Seating' column
for row in range(0, len(df)):
store = re.findall(boxing_pattern, df.iat[row, index_description])
df.iat[row, index_boxing] = store


df.loc[df['BOX DESCRIPTION'] == 'BOXES (1-1,800 GQ) NEW STORE','BOX DESCRIPTION'] = 'BOXES NEW STORE'
df.loc[df['BOX DESCRIPTION'] == 'BOXES (1-1,999 SF) NEW STORE','BOXES'] = '(1-1,800 GQ)'

df.loc[df['BOX DESCRIPTION'] == 'BOXES (61-150) OLD STORE','BOX DESCRIPTION'] = 'BOXES OLD 
STORE'


print(df.head(265))
```

I am just trying to extract the following:
BOXES **(1-1,999 SF)** LOW RISK
BOXES **(61-150)** LOW RISK

```
# sample dataframe
            BOX DESCRIPTION
0   NEW STORE
1  BOXES STORE (1-1,999 SF) LOW RISK
2  BOXES (61-150) HIGH RISK
3  BOXES (0-30) MODERATE RISK
4  BOXES (151 + ) HIGH RISK
5  BOXES (151 + ) LOW RISK
6  BOXES (151 + ) MODERATE RISK
7  BOXES (31-60)  LOW RISK
8  BOXES (0-30)  HIGH RISK
9  BOXES (31-60) HIGH RISK
10 BOXES (0-30)  LOW RISK
11 BOXES (2,000+ SF) MODERATE RISK
12 BOXES (2,000+ SF) LOW RISK
13 BOXES (2,000+ SF) HIGH RISK
14 BOXES STORE (1-1,999 SF) MODERATE
15 BOXES STORE (1-1,999 SF) HIGH RISK
16 BOXES (61-150) LOW RISK
17 BOXES (61-150) MODERATE RISK
18 BOXES (31-60) MODERATE RISK

EXPECTED OUT

            BOX DESCRIPTION
0   NEW STORE                      BOXES
1  BOXES STORE LOW RISK            (1,1-999 SF)
2  BOXES  LOW RISK                 (61 - 150)
3  BOXES (0-30) MODERATE RISK
4  BOXES (151 + ) HIGH RISK
5  BOXES (151 + ) LOW RISK
6  BOXES (151 + ) MODERATE RISK
7  BOXES (31-60)  LOW RISK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` to extract the required pattern from `BOX DESCRIPTION`:

```
p = r'\s*(\(61-150\)|\(1-1,999 SF\))\s*'
s = df['BOX DESCRIPTION'].str.extract(fr'(.*?){p}(.*)')
df['BOXES'], df['BOX DESCRIPTION'] = s[1], (s[0] + ' ' + s[2]).fillna(df['BOX DESCRIPTION'])
```

Alternatively you can first extract the required pattern from `BOX DESCRIPTION` then assign it to `BOXES` then `replace` the pattern and assign the result back to `BOX DESCRIPTION`:

```
p = r'\s*(\(61-150\)|\(1-1,999 SF\))\s*'
df['BOXES'] = df['BOX DESCRIPTION'].str.extract(p, expand=False)
df['BOX DESCRIPTION'] = df['BOX DESCRIPTION'].str.replace(p, ' ')
```

Result:

```
              BOX DESCRIPTION         BOXES
0                   NEW STORE           NaN
1        BOXES STORE LOW RISK  (1-1,999 SF)
2             BOXES HIGH RISK      (61-150)
3  BOXES (0-30) MODERATE RISK           NaN
4    BOXES (151 + ) HIGH RISK           NaN
```

Comment: Hi this works perfectly thanks, however, i have more digits and values within the 'BOX DESCRIPTION' column. I would like to just extract these specific values only that I provided but this pat extracts all digits to the new column boxes. How would i change the pattern to reflect this?

Comment: @CoderMan Can you please provide some sample data and expected out for the same?

Comment: I updated the post with sample data and expected outputs

Comment: @CoderMan Edited the answer according to your data.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly. Need to brush up on my regex skills